# Why do minecraft blocks reload?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

I have minecraft turned up to max settings (GTX 770, quad core 4.0 GHz intel i7, 240 GB SSD, 32 GB RAM) and for some reason the max distance blocks are slowly loading over time (not at once) and when I hit blocks they reload right away or after a few seconds.

Do I have the settings incorrect or something? Does this just happen for a minute while everything loads or is there something I'm missing?

I'm playing on Linux Kubuntu 14.04 btw

Comment: on what version are you playing?

Comment: What Java version do you have installed? I'd recommend only having a newish Java 8 (64-bit if possible) and removing any others. Not entirely sure if this is the case for Linux, though.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like your minecraft is running a little low on memory. You have 32GB of RAM but minecraft will only use 1GB by default.

In your launcher, edit your profile. There are 2 check-boxes very near the bottom with text boxes next to them. They are labelled "Java ___". The second one will have text such as "-Xm1024M". The "1024M" is the memory being allocated to minecraft. DO NOT set this to "32G" as this will kill your computer. "4G" is more than enough but if that is still too slow, don't go above "16G".

Hope this helped.